# Join in Simple Report using MS Access in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, ms-access-2007

i have Windows Application in C#.Net 2010.
I have connected Database in MS Access 2007 using oledb Connection

now  i have added simple ReportViewer (Not Crystal Report Viewer) and using that i have designed Simple Report using DataSet. 
It displays data with one table fine.

but i want to fetch data from multiple table using INNER JOINs, Is there any stored procedure or View exists in MS Access 2007, Or any Connectivity with Reports in VS 2010?

Thanks//

Answer (score 1):

MS Access 2007 allows for views. You can create a view in MS Access with the data that you need. The syntax for creating views can be found here:

[CREATE VIEW Statement (Microsoft Access SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177895%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but where can i find functionality to create view in MS Access 2007 ?

Comment: You create the views in Access, and call them just like you would a table in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But how to create view in MS Access, (i dont need syntax, but i need steps to create view in MS Access 2007)

Comment: It has to be done with SQL. Your only other option is to use the Query Builder in Access.

Comment: Just create a query then, the outcome is the same.